# bank program with array

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I am given 3 members of base class which are all arrays(string, int, double), and I want to somehow link elements of the array together. I need the output to be inherited to the derived classes.

```
class Account{
protected:
string acc_name[3]={"He","Me","She"};
int acc_no[3]={11111,22222,33333};
double acc_balance[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};
};
```

So for example, when I input the "acc_no" of '11111' in the user input, it will know which "acc_name" ("He") to output and its corresponding balance.

```
class Login:protected Account{
public:
void info(){
cout<<"Enter AccNo: ";
cin<<acc_no[3];
cout<<"Hello "<<acc_name[3];
```

> ideally the string "He" gets outputted here right after Hello

Currently, I'm stuck not knowing how to proceed. How do i do this? Just started programming not too long ago.

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: If you don't know it's often because you try to optimize it to early. Don't. Make the most naive implementation you can following the instructions. When you've got that working, look at it as see if you see patterns that you could put into functions to reuse code etc. Do that a lot and you'll see some patterns early and some are still a mystery - to make it fun :-)

Answer (score -1):

First of all man, the cin operator "<<" is supposed to be the opposite... ">>".. I suggest you create an algorithm first... you are going to need more varible tho.. hope that was any help.. its my first time responding to one of these

Comment: Sorry to ask but what more variable do i need to add, could you give me an inkling as to what i might have to add? Thanks.

Comment: you'd need to add a variable to store the user's account number, then check if it is equal to any such number in the array, then depending on the user's account number.. that will determine their name.. (if both the arrays are in order.. i would suggest using a counter to get the name of the user) dm if you need any help.. quarrentine is boring)